# How do I print "∩" in c language?

Tags: c, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I want to print the intersection symbol(∩) in C but it doesn't exist on the [ASCII table](https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-a-circumflex-accent-a-circumflex-lowercase-ascii-code-131.html). The problem is that everything I try generates some weird nonsense output like Ôê®.

At first I tried just putting it on the printf function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("∩");
    return 0;
}
```

After that didn't work, I searched for the charachter encoding on the internet and found it [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2229), so I decide to try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("\xE2\x88\xA9");
    return 0;
}
```

It still did not work. After more research, I thought that changing the locale would help me, and I tried doing so:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8");
    printf("\xE2\x88\xA9");
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried this:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("\xE2\x88\xA9");
    return 0;
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    printf("\xE2\x88\xA9");
    return 0;
}
```

Then I found some page on the internet(unfortunately I forgot where it was and couldn't find it again) that told me to use a function called wprintf, and I did so:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8");
    wprintf(L"\xE2\x88\xA9");
    return 0;
}
```

All the previous code result in the same output:

```
Ôê®
```

If someone could help me print the "∩" charachter, I would be grateful.

**EDIT:** As suggested, I tried using a function from windows.h to set the code page to what I need, but it still only works on the code editor:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#if defined(_WIN32) 
    #define W 1
#else 
    #define W 0
#endif

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8");

    if (W) // If the OS is windows
    {
        SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
        wprintf(L"\xE2\x88\xA9\n");
        SetConsoleOutputCP(850); // Set it back to normal to print other stuff later
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Like I said, the problem stated in my comment still persists, it works on the code editor, but not whenever i run it on the winows command prompt.

Comment: What platform?  Linux? Mac? Windows?  Your C code is probably fine; your problem probably has to do with your window display settings.  (For example, many people here have reported difficulties getting UTF-8 output from their C programs  to display properly under Windows.)

Comment: On Windows you might like to try this command before running your app: `mode con cp select=65001`. It changes your console encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: @thebusybee ```mode con cp select=6500```1 works on the integraded terminal of my code editor, but still prints Ôê® if I run it on the windows command prompt or if I run it by clicking on the .exe file. And even when it works it prints a lot  stuff that messes up the output of the program.

Comment: Sure, this mode change is just temporary for the current console. You might like to search for hints how to run a batch file on each console start. For a console program started by double clicking you might also like to search the Windows API; IIRC `SetConsoleOutputCP()` might be a good start.

Comment: @thebusybee I did just that and still have the same problem. I edited the post so my solution can be seen.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I don't use Windows at home, but I have to at work. Anyway, it works for me. If I remove the `setlocale()` and `SetConsoleOutputCP()` calls and try different codepages I get different outputs: "âˆ©" with 1252, "Ôê®" with 850, and "∩" with 65001. Are you sure you are running the correct executable?

Comment: `E2 88 A9` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `∩` (Unicode codepoint `U+2229`). Using `"\xE2\x88\xA9"` is fine in a narrow `char` string, provided the console is setup to handle UTF-8 output. But when printing a wide Unicode string, `L"\xE2\x88\xA9"` needs to be `L"\x2229"` instead, or simply `L"∩"`. You don't want to put UTF-8 codeunits into a wide string that is not meant to be UTF-8 encoded. `wchar_t` strings are encoded in UTF-16 on Windows and in UTF-32 on other platforms.